# Assign column from one dataframe to another dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to assign `item_name` from first daframe to second dataframe by creating a new column base on first dataframe.

This is the sample dataframe #1

[image]

The second dataframe look like this:

[image]

I tried using this code, but it is not working. I guess, it is because of same data from `item_id` column?

```
new_df1 = (
  df1.select
  .join(
    df2
    df1.item_id = df2.item_id,
    "left"
    )
)
```

Expected output is this:

[image]

Comment: Selecting `item_id` and `item_name` from the first dataframe would produce the expected output. Why do you want to join something?

Answer (score 0):

Apply `join` with selection:

`df2.join(df1, df1.item_id = df2.item_id, "left").select('df2.item_id', 'df1.item_name')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join like this:

```
new_df = df2.join(df1.select('item_id', 'item_name'), 'item_id', 'left')
```